# Opening Multiple TCP Connections From A Client To A Server Using Random Source Port In C

Tags: c, sockets

I am writing a C program where for every new request to be processed by server, I need to open a new TCP connection? That is every request from client needs to be handled by a separate TCP connection to a server listening on a particular port.

Can someone help me in code pointers?

- How to maintain array of this socket identifiers (multiple sockets that needs to be opened)
- How will I be able to read (Need to scroll through all open sockets and see if something interesting is to be read upon that socket)

Any code snippet will be highly useful?

Comment: Why would want or need to open a new conenction for each request? Surely it woudl be better to oen a single connection from client to servr, keep it open and use streams (or whetevere) to coummunicate?

Comment: @Mawg: I have an application interacting with a protocol involving multistage authentication(multiple request/response). So, for concurrent users logging in for authentication, what happens is before this multi-stage authentication for user1 gets completed, a new user-authentication request comes in on same TCP connection. This server doesn;t like it and throws invalid credentials for both the users(although credentials are valid). Hence, to handle concurrency of users, i am planning to open multiple TCP connection rater than reusing the sae

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `select()` function (assuming you are working with `<sys/socket.h>`), "gives you the power to monitor several sockets at the same time. It'll tell you which ones are ready for reading, which are ready for writing, and which sockets have raised exceptions" from http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/ (here you can download a pretty good book on network programming basics).

For a server example using select check http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/selectserver.c

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save state with the socket, put it in a `struct` together with the data you need, and link the structures together as a list. For checking which sockets are ready see Maluchi's answer.